# Header alignment problem in jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a problem with the implementation of a DataTable in jQuery. My DataTable is dynamically generated and the table content changes in size.

For some reason the header is not always aligned with the other rows. This table can scroll in X and Y directions, the presence of the one or the other depends on the content size.

In order to fix the problem, I tried to add the following code:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$('#container').css('display', 'block');
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Maybe I'm wrong the position in the code or this is not the right solution.
What could be the problem? Can anyone help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "scrollY": 250,
    "pageLength": 25,
    "scrollX": true,
    "sScrollXInner": "100%",
    "bSort": true,
    "dom": '<lf<t>ip>',
    "rowCallback": function(row, data, index) {
      if (data[4] == "0") {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', '#fca4a4');
      } else if (data[4] == 1) {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', '#c7e6c3');
      } else {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', '#b3b8b2');
      }
    }
  });

  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  // Hide two columns
  table.columns([4]).visible(false);
});
```

This is an example of the table content:

```
<div>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap no-footer" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:5px"><thead><tr><th>Path names</th><th>Path String</th><th>Distance</th><th>Path Length</th><th>Final Effect</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>NF2-->DIFFERENTIATION</td><td>NF2--> LATS2--| WWTR1--> MYOD1--> DIFFERENTIATION</td><td>1.24</td><td>4</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>NF2-->DIFFERENTIATION</td><td>NF2--> LATS1--| WWTR1--> MYOD1--> DIFFERENTIATION</td><td>1.3</td><td>4</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

I add all css and js files that are needed to Data Table visualization.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mydirectoryPath/css/styleResults_pathway.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mydirectoryPath/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mydirectoryPath/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mydirectoryPath/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mydirectoryPath/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./mydirectoryPath/js/jquery-3.3.1.js">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./mydirectoryPath/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    </script>
<!--script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./mydirectoryPath/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js">
    </script-->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./mydirectoryPath/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
```

Actually, I have now figured out that the code, taken alone, is correct. In fact, in order to reproduce this example to explain the problem, I extracted the data table object in a simple html file and the header is correctly aligned, then the problem could be due to some styles that are not correctly uploaded in the original page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "scrollY": 250,
    "pageLength": 25,
    "scrollX": true,
    "sScrollXInner": "100%",
    "bSort": true,
    "dom": '<lf<t>ip>',
    "rowCallback": function(row, data, index) {
      if (data[4] == "0") {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', '#fca4a4');
      } else if (data[4] == 1) {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', '#c7e6c3');
      } else {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', '#b3b8b2');
      }
    }
  });

  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  // Hide two columns
  table.columns([4]).visible(false);
});
```

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting { background: url('./images/sort_both.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc { background: url('./images/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc { background: url('./images/sort_desc.png') no-repeat center right; }

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled { background: url('./images/sort_asc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled { background: url('./images/sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
  background-image: none!important;
}
th {

    text-align:center;
    font-size: 10pt;

}

td {

    text-align:center;
    font-size: 8pt;

}


tr {
        text-align:center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width:100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!--script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./mydirectoryPath/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script-->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mydirectoryPath/css/styleResults_pathway.css">-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap no-footer" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:5px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Path names</th>
        <th>Path String</th>
        <th>Distance</th>
        <th>Path Length</th>
        <th>Final Effect</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>NF2-->DIFFERENTIATION</td>
        <td>NF2--> LATS2--| WWTR1--> MYOD1--> DIFFERENTIATION</td>
        <td>1.24</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NF2-->DIFFERENTIATION</td>
        <td>NF2--> LATS1--| WWTR1--> MYOD1--> DIFFERENTIATION</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

About the css styleResults_pathway.css I added here more details:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting { background: url('./images/sort_both.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc { background: url('./images/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc { background: url('./images/sort_desc.png') no-repeat center right; }

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled { background: url('./images/sort_asc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled { background: url('./images/sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
  background-image: none!important;
}
th {

    text-align:center;
    font-size: 10pt;

}

td {

    text-align:center;
    font-size: 8pt;

}


tr {
        text-align:center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width:100%;

}
```

Comment: Can you please add the html code (preferably in a snippet) and if needed css so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: For completeness, I add the style of the table referred to the Data Table properties. $style = 'id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap no-footer"

Comment: @MarkBaijens
I added more details in the main text of the question. Thanks

Comment: I created a snippet of your code and can't reproduce your issue. Please provide (the minimal amount of) code to reproduce your issue. The problem might be in `styleResults_pathway.css` but I have no idea what this is and couldn't find external library for it.

Comment: Exactly what I said,  in the same way, I can't reproduce the issue in a simple code with only the part of Data Table code. 
Sorry, now I added the properties in that css. Actually, it is difficult to provide the whole code, I just specify that I create the table object with a php function that takes as input the content and returns the table in html format and then I print inside the div block.

Comment: Have you tried with adding class 'table-responsive' at your div element before table ?

Comment: @MarkBaijens
I fixed the problem, thanks to the trials that I have done for providing you a better explanation of the problem. I noticed that in the upper part of my original code there were some style statements that I should have to remove. Thanks for for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to you, You should add responsive:true properties in Datatable function like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "scrollY": 250,
    "pageLength": 25,
    "scrollX": true,
    "sScrollXInner": "100%",
    "bSort": true,
    "dom": '<lf<t>ip>',
    "rowCallback": function(row, data, index) {
      if (data[4] == "0") {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', '#fca4a4');
      } else if (data[4] == 1) {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', '#c7e6c3');
      } else {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', '#b3b8b2');
      }
    }
  });

  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  // Hide two columns
  table.columns([4]).visible(false);
});
```